# Convolutional Neural Network in Tensorflow for Prediction

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am a beginner in CNN and Tensorflow.

I saw many examples of Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) for classification. However, I need CNNs for regression. I am trying to implement CNN in Tensorflow with own data for prediction.

Can I implement CNN for prediction or are CNNs only for classification?

Can you give me any documentation or clue of doing CNN for prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm a beginner myself, and have not applied such a model, I can point you to this answer: [Using deep learning for time series prediction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68662/using-deep-learning-for-time-series-prediction#68677).

Additionally, while it's not exactly prediction, in one classification project I worked on, besides the actual classification, I had to see how the input relates to other classes. Think of a handwritten number 9, but with a longer tail going up. While it was still classified as a 9, it was "closer" to 8 than a normal 9.

I don't know if this is necessarily a good idea or feasible for your project, but maybe you can generalise a classifier to give a point in the space described by your classes instead of a discrete value.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I implement CNN for prediction or are CNNs only for classification?

Both, regression and classification, are often called prediction. And yes, you can do both with CNNs. It is only the loss function (mean squared error for regression, cross entropy for classification) and the labels (the regression values for regression, one-hot encoding for classification) which are changed.

I suggest to go through a tutorial. I can recommend:

- [CS231](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/)
- [Tensorflow Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/)